# How do you pass HTML input files to C# ASP.Net using AjaxFileUpload.js?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, jsajaxfileuploader

I'm new to stackoverflow so my apologies if I misuse any of the guidelines. I am in the middle of making a ASP.Net website and I have run into a very specific problem where I am using `ProcessRequest` to try and retrieve multiple files.

**C# ASP.Net Code**

The variable `files` is not retreiving requested files `context.Request.Files`

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
     try
     {
          var files = context.Request.Files;

          for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
          {
               //Checking to see if the files exist
               var postedFile = files[i];
          }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          context.Response.Write(e.Message);
     }
}
```

I am trying to avoid refreshing the web page and types of `submit` to allow the user to navigate through the content fluently. I believe my problem stems from dynamically adding my input file html elements from the C# backend.

**HTML**

```
<div id='fmAddFiles'>
    <input id='fileUploader' type='file' multiple='true' runat='server'/>
    <input id='addFilesBtn' type='button' value='Add Files'/>
</div>
<div id='fmSubmit'><input id='uploadBtn' type='button' value='Upload'/></div>
```

I have bound click and trigger events for `addFilesBtn` and `fileUploader` and they get hit correctly. It is when I attempt to pass the files to the backend using `$.ajaxFileUpload` that nothing happens.

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
     url: 'WebHandler.ashx',
     async: false,
     secureuri: false,
     fileElementId: 'fileUploader',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data, status) {
          alert(data);
     },
     error: function (data, status, e) {
          alert(e);
     }
});
```

All the mentioned functions get hit just I can't for the life of me can't figure out why it is not retrieving any of the files.

Where might I be going wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried adding static elements to my html and found out that the server control does not work when dynamically adding elements. The `runat='server'` tag no longer works when this is done.

Now I am a crossroads. Is there a way to bind the server control to an element or am I going to have to use a bunch of CSS tricks? Which to me is rather messy at the best of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of a light bulb moment before where I realised that I was already hiding `fileUploader`. All I did was made it static and made sure the selectors used the server control ID so that `uploadBtn` was able to trigger it.

Also had a look at Prasad Raja's answer thoroughly as well and would recommend anyone starting a new project to consider it. Was very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the source code here..

Js uploadFile
[Reference](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)

just check it let me know..
[File Upload Example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9FC54C5F947E1701!1182&authkey=!ANophbgr7vP5ii4&ithint=file%2Crar)

Handler.ashx

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FolderPath" value="/Resources/UploadFiles/" />
  </appSettings>

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Expires = -1;
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
                string savepath = "";
                string tempPath = "";
                tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
                savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
                string filename = postedFile.FileName;
                if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
                }
                postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + filename);
                context.Response.Write(tempPath + "/" + filename);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```